# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: NoneType

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-views

I am getting this error in production (heroku/postgres) but not in local(sqlite).

```
class ModelC(models.Model):
    model_c_field_1 = models.ForeignKey(Venue, null = True, blank= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_c_field_2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_c_field_1= models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)



def function(request, userprofile_id):
    
    latest_model_object = ModelB.objects.filter(user=userprofile_id).order_by('-id')[:1]
 
    time_delta = ()
    for ModelB in latest_model_object:
        
         time_delta = timezone.now() - modelb.created_at
    
    time_delta_rule = ModelC.objects.filter(venue=request.user.userprofile.venue)
    
    timedelta_test=timedelta()
    for ModelC in time_delta_rule:
        
            timedelta_test = timedelta(hours = ModelC.timeframe)
            print(timedelta_test)
```

examples of print result: `0:00:00` or `1 day, 0:00:00`

Giving the below error.

```
2023-04-14T04:26:40.379344+00:00 app[web.1]: timedelta_test = timedelta(hours = modelc.timeframe)
2023-04-14T04:26:40.379344+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: NoneType
```

Comment: 1) The error is telling you the problem `ModelC.timeframe` is `NULL/None` and that can't be. 2) I don't see where `timeframe` is defined in `ModelC`. 3) You should develop against the same database you use in production.  I like `SQLite` but it is not like Postgres especially when it comes to data types.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The key was here `NULL/None` which help understand my problem. The error was being showed as timeframe was `empty`, as this specific model object didnt need anything in it and didnt realise it would be problem. I added an if statement in the views to avoid the problem.